# How do we add column value in spark using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data like this

```
+-------------+--------+--------+
|         COl1|    Col2|    COL3|
+-------------+--------+--------+
|A .......... |   56102|   45991|
|B........... |   25336|   23099|
+-------------+--------+--------+
```

it should be like this

```
+-------------+--------+--------+
|         COl1|    Col2|    COL3|
+-------------+--------+--------+
|A .......... |   56102|   45991|
|B........... |   25336|   23099|
|Total....... |   58368|   69090|
+-------------+--------+--------+
```

need a row with Total and the value should be the sum of reaming row in the dataframe.

Comment: Just use a Union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation functions to compute the sums, and a union to append them at the end of the original df. For it to work, you just need to make sure that the names of the columns coincide.

It would go like this:

```scala
val df = Seq(("A", 56102, 45991), ("B",  25336, 23099))
    .toDF("COL1", "COL2", "COL3")

val sums = df.select(lit("Total") as "COL1", sum('COL2) as "COL2", sum('COL3) as "COL3")
df.union(sums).show()
+-----+-----+-----+
| COL1| COL2| COL3|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    A|56102|45991|
|    B|25336|23099|
|Total|81438|69090|
+-----+-----+-----+
```